# display 2 tables with checkboxes by ajax button

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am altering a form and placing a new 'button' . On the press of the button, using the #ajax property , I want to display 2 separate tables with checkboxes for each row. Each table has separate data.

The 2 tables should be initially hidden and should become visible on button press. How should I proceed with this ??

The table data is fetched from database and some operations are performed on it.. so where should I put this code ? In the callback function ?

Update- I tried to implement this by using tableselect, but the checked boxes aren't returning the values in the $form_state['values']. You can check out the code [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39726/form-statevalues-for-table-select-returning-empty-arrays#comment40370_39726) 
 or suggest me a simpler interface to implement.

Comment: I need more clarification of the question in order to properly answer. If I understand you correctly, I think I have a solution. I need more clarification with the most simplified code example that illustrates your problem. Please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: Please clarify your question or you can specify the code here and write where you get the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the table-building code in the ajax callback. Put the code to build the tables into the hook_form_alter() implementation that you are using to add the button. You can use $form_state['triggering_element'] to tell if the button has been pressed, and only execute the query and build the tables if you need to.