# $form_state['values'] for table select returning empty arrays

Tags: forms

I have my two table-select as -

```
    $form['mltag_new']['tag'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t("Suggest Tags"),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'mltag_suggest_tags_ajax',
        'wrapper' => 'mltag_suggest_tags_table_div',
        'effect' => 'slide',
        ),
     );

    $form['mltag_new']['myselector'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="mltag_suggest_tags_table_div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['implicit_tags'] = array(
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#title' => 'My Selector',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#attribute' => array('style' => 'display:none;'),           
    );

    $header_learn_tags = array(
        'sno ' => t('S. No.'),
        'tags' => t('Tags'),
    );

    $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['learn_tags'] = array(
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#title' => 'Tags from Learning',
        '#header' => $header_learn_tags,
        '#attribute' => array('style' => 'display:none;'),
    );
$form['#submit'][] = 'mltag_custom_submit_function';
```

The values- $options are being set by an ajax callback activated on the press of a button. But when I am trying to capture the values checked by the user in the table in my mltag_custom_submit_function it returns an **empty array**. The code I am using is-

```
    $selected_uids = $form_state['values']['mltag_new']['myselector']['implicit_tags'];
    drupal_set_message(print_r($form_state['values'], TRUE));
```

How can I capture the values selected by the user in the table correctly ?

**Edit -**

definition for $form['mltag_new']

```
$form['mltag_new'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('MLTag settings'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => -2,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('mltag-settings')),
    );
```

also a short snippet of my ajax function is this-

```
function mltag_suggest_tags_ajax($form, &$form_state) {     

      $output = '';
      $tags = some_function_call();
      $algo = variable_get('algo_type');
        if ($algo == 1) {
          $header = array(
              'tag' => t('Tag'),
              'frequency' => t('Frequency'), 
              );

          $options = array();      
          foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
            $options[$key] = array(
                'tag' => $key,
                'frequency' => $value,
                );
    }
    }

      //returning values for tableselect
      $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['implicit_tags']['#header'] = $header; 
      $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['implicit_tags']['#options'] = $options;
      $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['implicit_tags'] = form_process_tableselect($form['mltag_new']['myselector']['implicit_tags']);

      $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['learn_tags']['#header'] = $header_learn_tags;
      $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['learn_tags']['#options'] = $options_learn;
      $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['learn_tags'] = form_process_tableselect($form['mltag_new']['myselector']['learn_tags']);
     return $form['mltag_new']['myselector'];
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of the `$form['mltag_new']` element as well?

Comment: added.. this is a part of the add/edit article page

Comment: I might be missing something but you say the options are added by an ajax callback...I don't see the `#ajax` property anywhere on your form, have you added it in another bit of code?

Comment: the ajax property is activated on a button press.. i didn't add it earlier just to keep things simpler and short.. but wait I'll add it now and also my ajax function call

Comment: @Clive- I just noticed the HTML for the checkbox that gets rendered by using the above code-
<input type="checkbox" value="scientist" class="form-checkbox">
could this possibly be the cause of error ?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, that looks like valid HTML (albeit not XHTML) to me. What makes you think that's the problem? If you mean that it's a checkbox instead of checkboxes, that's just how a tableselect works as far as I know

Comment: it is valid HTML but see what i did was just for testing purpose i added another static tableselect to the page, below the above two with some row values. Here's how the HTML code for one of it's checboxes looks like -


<input type="checkbox" id="edit-mltag-new-test-table-test1" name="mltag_new[test_table][test1]" value="test1" class="form-checkbox">


where test_table is the element id and test1 is the row id.. 
you can see the difference between this checkbox and the one rendered by ajax.

Comment: That is why I was wondering if this could be the cause for the ajax based tableselect values not to be captured by $form_state['values'] as their HTML is not being rendered properly

Comment: @Clive this patch at http://drupal.org/node/1458824 is regarding attaching #ajax property to the checkboxes displayed by tableselect, which is not what I am trying to do. I am only trying to retrieve the selected checkboxes, in the table